# metainfo Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sql, sharepoint

I'm doing a research about the Sharepoint database. 
The Sharepoint database has a table called alldocs. Within this table there is a column called "metainfo". The "metainfo"column is in a binarystream format, and should represent a metadict format.

My Question:
What information is stored in the metainfo column? 
How do I convert this binstream to something readable?

Comment: It is not recommended, nor allowed to work directly with the SharePoint database according to Microsoft.

Comment: But that is not the point is it?

Comment: No, hence this is a comment and not an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this question is old, but I just needed to figure this out myself and thought the answer might help someone.

To read the metainfo column you can use the following SQL:

`Cast(Cast(metainfo AS varbinary(2048)) As varchar(2048))`